# java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 28

Tags: java, patternsyntaxexception

```
public class samppatmatch {

    private boolean validatingpswwithpattern(String password){
        String math="[a-zA-z0-9]+[(]+(?:[^\\]+|\\.)*";
        Pattern pswNamePtrn =Pattern.compile(math);
        boolean flag=false;

         Matcher mtch = pswNamePtrn.matcher(password);
         if(mtch.matches()){
             flag= true;
         }

        return flag;
    }


    public static void main(String args[]){
        samppatmatch obj=new samppatmatch();
        boolean b=obj.validatingpswwithpattern("");
         System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

I am getting this type of exception for above code:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 28
```

Comment: you need to escape the `(` as `\\(`

Comment: In addtion `[^\\]` doesn´t compile because you escape the `]` and the char class is never closed.

Comment: @KevinEsche Actually, according to [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iP4zT5/1), you don't _need_ to escape a paranthesis `()` inside a character group. The exception also doesn't refer to that paranthesis but rather the second issue you noted (the 29th character is the closing paranthesis `)` right before the end of the regex).

Answer (score 0):

The expression `[^\\]` causes the regular expression compiler to crash (@KevinEsche noted that in a comment) because the closing bracket `]` was escaped. If you wanted to create a character class containing a `\`, you need to escape it as well so that the character class would look like this in a Java string: `[^\\\\]`

Answer (score 0):

The expression is invalid.

The closing bracket will be escape because you used `'\\]'` in the expression.

solution 1: You can use like `' \\\\] '`.

or

solution 2: You can handle the exception to get user friendly message like below,

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException;

public class samppatmatch {

    private boolean validatingpswwithpattern(String password) {
        boolean flag = false;
        try {
            String math = "[a-zA-z0-9]+[(]+(?:[^\\]+|\\.)*";
            Pattern pswNamePtrn = Pattern.compile(math);
            Matcher mtch = pswNamePtrn.matcher(password);
            if (mtch.matches()) {
                flag = true;
            }

        } catch (PatternSyntaxException pe) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Expression");
        }
        return flag;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        samppatmatch obj = new samppatmatch();
        boolean b = obj.validatingpswwithpattern("Admin@123");
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```